# Sed: substitute pattern, not limited to matching line, but to another pattern

Tags: xml, sed, substitution

I would like to surround multiple words with quotes.
Easily done task with sed and grouping.

Except that my words are located in an attribute of an xml tag.

```
<daddy>
    <son name="blabla">
        <belongs having="car cat doll" color="yellow" />
    </son>
</daddy>
```

I want `having` attribute to be postprocessed to `"'car' 'cat' 'doll'"`.
`having` is a uniquely affected attribute name.
So, no danger to match only this word, it will automatically be part of a `belongs` tag.
I think this is a good start to be able to use sed here, and don't do hard things with heavy tools, and xml readers.

My first attempt was to match the pattern to filter the lines, and try to surround the words. But it surrounds them, matching in the whole line, and not only in the first pattern. Which is what I wanted.

```
sed "/having=\"[a-z ]\+\"/ s/\([a-z]\+\)/'\1'/g"
```

.

```
<daddy>
    <son name="blabla">
        <'belongs' 'having'="'car' 'cat' 'doll'" 'color'="'yellow'" />
    </son>
</daddy>
```

My second attempt, with group matching led me no more further...

```
sed "s/havings=\"\(\([a-z]\+\) \?\)*\"/havings=\"'\2'\"/g"
```

.

```
<daddy>
    <son name="blabla">
        <belongs having="'doll'" color="yellow"/>
    </son>
</daddy>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ":a
/having/ {
   s/\"\(\( *'[^ ]\{1,\}'\)* *\)\([^ '\"]\{1,\}\)\([^\"]*\)\"/\"\1'\3'\4\"/
   t a
   }" YourFile
```

replace each group of word (char that are not space or quote or double quote) by itself surrounded by simple quote. use a recursif to change word that are between a double quote after all group of word surrounded by simple quote. This because, option `g` cannot be used with back reference, so work around use groupe by taking a big group of all word  that are previously quoted, cycling until ther is no more unquoted word

I assume that the content is on 1 line (because of sed default behaviour) and the same line as `having`

Comment: I am amazed by your sed skills... I have still so much to learn ! The problem is that your command affects all the double-quoted fields. And my example did not mention it (my bad) but there may be others attributes in the line. Though, you assumed well for other things. Thanks ! I edit my question.

Comment: sorry, going on holliday (back mid aug) and a bit in a hurry now so i don't have time to adapt. I think a small adaption thtat also exclude `"` in sub group will solve the problem (and include `having=`in the first part to isolate this form the rest of the line) will be enough

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give up using only sed...
I did something which is awful and tends to produce errors in substitutions...
But I will diff my ouputs afterwards.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

O=$IFS

# For every file passed in argument
for f in "$@"
do
    IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
    # For every field content
    for p in $(egrep -o 'having="[^"]*"' $f | egrep -o '".*"' | grep -v '&quote;' | sort -u);
    do
        # Match every occurrence of this content on the lines of "having" and surround its words
        sed "/having/ s/$p/$(echo $p | sed 's/\([a-z]\+\)/\&quote;\1\&quote;/g')/" $f -i
    done
    IFS=$O
done
```